# What is the distribution of sum of a Rayleigh and a Log-logistic distributed independent r.v.?

Tags: statistics

Let Z = X + Y. X follows the Rayleigh distribution given by
\begin{equation}
  f_X(x;\sigma_1) = \frac{x}{\sigma_1^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right), \; x \geq 0
  \label{RayleighPDF}
\end{equation}
and Y follows the Loglogistic distribution given by
\begin{equation}
  f_Y(y;\sigma_2,\mu) = \frac{\exp(\rho)}{\sigma_2 y \left[1 + \exp(\rho)\right]^2}, \; y \geq 0
  \label{LoglogisticPDF}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  \rho = \frac{\log(y) - \mu}{\sigma_2}
  \label{def_rho}
\end{equation}
Assuming X and Y are independent, what is the distribution of Z?

Comment: Notation conflict:  you have defined $Z$ to be 2 different and conflicting things. Also, you need to specify whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent, or the nature of the dependence.

Comment: Sorry for the mixed-up. Yes, X and Y are independent (this makes life a lot easier) and z as defined in the last two equations should be given a different symbol, say \rho.